# Error ocur while running web logic server in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;D:\harinni\project\liferay\apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.tar\apache-ant-1.8.2-bin\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b50)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore6737169194810782409.jks -Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1 -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:57 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:57 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:57 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 19.1-b02 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:57 PM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.5.0  Fri Apr 1 20:20:06 PDT 2011 1398638 > 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:58 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:58 PM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:58 PM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:58 PM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log01054. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log.> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:27:58 PM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:374)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:288)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.getElementText(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:4815)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.processFunction(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:2163)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.processFunctions(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:2072)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.processAppPolicy(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:796)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.processPolicyStore(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:521)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:187)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.loadXmlDataStore(XmlDataStore.java:411)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.<init>(XmlDataStore.java:276)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.getInstance(XmlDataStore.java:209)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.buildFromFile(XmlPolicyStore.java:492)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.<init>(XmlPolicyStore.java:276)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:100)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:74)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.findServiceInstance(ContextFactoryImpl.java:139)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.getContext(ContextFactoryImpl.java:170)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.getContext(ContextFactoryImpl.java:191)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.JpsContextFactoryImpl.getContext(JpsContextFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.JpsContextFactoryImpl.getContext(JpsContextFactoryImpl.java:127)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$2.run(PolicyUtil.java:2827)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$2.run(PolicyUtil.java:2821)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPDPService(PolicyUtil.java:2821)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getPDPService(PolicyUtil.java:3097)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.<init>(PolicyDelegationController.java:164)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.<init>(JavaPolicyProvider.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadOPSSPolicy(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1339)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1018)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<Jun 9, 2014 4:28:00 PM IST> <Error> <Security> <BEA-090892> <The loading of OPSS java security policy provider failed due to exception, see the exception stack trace or the server log file for root cause. If still see no obvious cause, enable the debug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more information. Error message: Cannot read from policy store. Reason is PolicyStore Error, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:28:00 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: The loading of OPSS java security policy provider failed due to exception, see the exception stack trace or the server log file for root cause. If still see no obvious cause, enable the debug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more information. Error message: Cannot read from policy store. Reason is PolicyStore Error, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: The loading of OPSS java security policy provider failed due to exception, see the exception stack trace or the server log file for root cause. If still see no obvious cause, enable the debug flag -Djava.security.debug=jpspolicy to get more information. Error message: Cannot read from policy store. Reason is PolicyStore Error, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadOPSSPolicy(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1398)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1018)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: Cannot read from policy store. Reason is PolicyStore Error, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.buildFromFile(XmlPolicyStore.java:496)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.<init>(XmlPolicyStore.java:276)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:100)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:74)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.findServiceInstance(ContextFactoryImpl.java:139)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:166)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:187)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.loadXmlDataStore(XmlDataStore.java:411)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.<init>(XmlDataStore.java:276)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:206)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:288)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.getElementText(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:4815)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.processFunction(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:2163)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Error at Line:3891, token:[EOF]Unbalanced ELEMENT got:function-return-typeame expected:function-return-type
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:374)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:288)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.StaxPolicyStoreParser.getElementText(StaxPolicyStoreParser.java:4815)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:28:00 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:28:00 PM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down> 
<Jun 9, 2014 4:28:00 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN> 
Process exited.
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `system-jazn-data.xml` is corrupted. Check if it's the case in the folder `C:\Users\LHO5COB\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain\config\fmwconfig`

If so you need to replace the `system-jazn-data.xml` by a valid one. To get a valid one I would suggest to create a new WLS domain and get a valid `system-jazn-data.xml` from that new domain.

Answer (score 0):

change "**program files x86**" to **progra~2** in **setDomainEnv.cmd**